# Table join comparing and creating a new column using that compare

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have 2 tables... table1 and table2.

I want to display all serial numbers from table1

table2 has also has serial numbers in it

I would like to compare the serial numbers in table1 with table2

I would then like to display all the serial numbers in table1 and have a second column with a yes if the serial number was in table1 or a no if it wasn't

Is this possible to do with a sql statement or do I have to build a seperate table? i'm running sql-server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If serial numbers in each table are unique then you could use:

```
SELECT  Table1.SerialNumber,
        CASE WHEN Table2.SerialNumber IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [IsInTable2]
FROM    Table1.SerialNumber
        LEFT JOIN Table2
            ON Table2.SerialNumber = Table1.SerialNumber
```

If there are Duplicates in one or both tables then either of the following will work:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        Table1.SerialNumber,
        COALESCE([IsInTable2], 'No') [IsInTable2]
FROM    Table1.SerialNumber
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 'Yes' [IsInTable2]
            FROM    Table2
            WHERE   Table2.SerialNumber = Table1.SerialNumber
        ) Table2


SELECT  DISTINCT
        Table1.SerialNumber,
        CASE WHEN Table2.SerialNumber IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END [IsInTable2]
FROM    Table1.SerialNumber
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  DISTINCT SerialNumber
            FROM    Table2
        ) Table2
            ON Table2.SerialNumber = Table1.SerialNumber
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Provides optimal query for unique serials and additional querys suitable for non-unique serials. Every better, provides a vanilla SQL query alongside the SQL Server-specific query. Really can't get an answer more comprehensive than that.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that the serial numbers are unique in each table then you can do an outer join. Using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will grab you all rows from the left side and optionally grab you any matching rows on the right side. Then you can do a comparison to see if a matching row was found in table2.

```
SELECT t1.serial, CASE WHEN t2.serial IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END
FROM table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.serial = t2.serial;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT t1.serialnumber as serialnumber, Case 
WHEN t1.serialnumber = t2.serialnumber then    'YES' else 'NO' END
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 with (nolock) on t1.serialnumber = t2.serialnumber;
```

Hopefully that should work